# How to create a private group chat in slack via keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, slack

I can jump to a conversation via ctrl + k and typing the contact's name. Yet how do I create a private group channel via keyboard shortcut only?

Currently, I have to use the mouse, go to the left sidebar, next to "DIRECT MESSAGES" and click the plus sign in order to open up a window to include different names to a new private channel containing of these people.

How to enter that window via a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

As of slack 3.0.5 (it was probably earlier but can't verify)

You hit `Ctrl + Shift + K` (Win/Lin) or `⌘ + Shift + K` (Mac)